# Is there a reason (other than free hosting) to publish war files to a maven repository?

Tags: maven, war

To me the main benefit of maven repositories is being able to use it as part of a build (i.e., using jar files from a maven repo). I could imagine a war file somehow being deployed via maven, but don't know if this is done in practice.

Comment: First you can use a war file as an overlay (usually used if you have js parts and others where you can put general js into a war and use it for others). Furthermore if you like to build EAR file you need WAR files as well. Furthermore you can deploy from a repository manager (which is usually better than using Maven for it)...also you can create tar.gz, zip files etc. which you can deploy so it makes sense to deplyo war,ear, tar.gz, zip to a maven repository usually handled by a repository manager ....and yes it's done in practice a lot...

Comment: Thanks @khmarbaise. We have some war files that we deploy in Tomcat. I was just wondering, if for external users, there would be any benefit for me publishing the war files to maven (vs, say, just uploading the war file to github releases).